# Linux command to check new files in file system

Tags: linux

We have linux machine we would like to check what new files have been added between a certain date range.

I only have SSH access to this box and it's openSUSE 11.1

Is there some sort of command that can give me a list of files that have been added to the filesystem between say 04/05/2011 and 05/05/2011

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are bunch of ways for doing that.

**First one:**

`start_date=201105040000`

`end_date=201105042359`

`touch -t ${start_date} start`

`touch -t ${end_date} end`

`find /you/path -type f -name '*you*pattern*' -newer start ! -newer end -exec ls -s {} \;`

**Second one:** 
find files modified between 20 and 21 days ago:

`find -ctime +20  -ctime -21`

finds files modified between 2500 and 2800 minutes ago:

`find -cmin +2500  -cmin -2800`

And read [this topic](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/) too.

Comment: note: `ctime` relates to file status and `mtime` relates to file contents/data

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Lucky these files have only been added and unmodified since than. Thus the find find -cmin +1080 -cmin -1500 gave me the results I wanted. Any change to output the date/time it was modified please?

Comment: I think its important to make clear that this answer will also return files that have been modified during your timeframe, but added well before.  So you should be careful.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use `find` to get a list of all the files that were last-*modified* in a certain time window, but that isn't quite what you want. I don't think you can tell just from a file's metadata when it came into existence.

Edit: To list the files along with their modification dates, you can pipe the output of `find` through `xargs` to run `ls -l` on all the files, which will show the modification time.

```
find /somepath -type f ... -print0 | xargs -0 -- ls -l
```

Comment: In my case I know for a fact that the last modified = create date since I m sure files where not modified. I used the command find -cmin +1000 -cmin -1500 and gave me the list of files :) .... and chance to output the date/time it was modified?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show how to list the modification date.

Comment: Splendid mate ... thank you very much. Just in case someone else reads this the ultimate command was:

find /mypath  -type f -cmin +1000 -cmin -1500  -print0 | xargs -0 -- ls -l`code`

Comment: I think its important to make clear that this answer will also return files that have been modified during your timeframe, but added well before.  So you should be careful.

Comment: jedwards, read the first comment. The OP can guarantee that for his files, the modification time *is* the creation time.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood your question.  Depending on what filesystem you are using, it may or may not store creation time.

My understanding is that ext2/3/4 do not store creation time, but modified, changed (status, which is slightly different), and access times are.

Fat32 on the other hand does contain creation timestamps IIRC.

If you are using an ext filesystem, you have two options it seems:

1.Settle for finding all of the files that were modified between two dates (which will include created files, but also files that were just edited).  You could do this using [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

2.Create a script/cronjob that will document the contents of your filesystem at some interval, e.g.

```
find / > filesystem.$(date +%s).log
```

and then run diffs to see what has been added.  This, of course, would prevent you from looking backwards to time before you started making these logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these:

```
find -newerct "1 Aug 2013" ! -newerct "1 Sep 2013" -ls

find . -mtime $(date +%s -d"Jan 1, 2013 23:59:59") -mtime $(date +%s -d"Jan 2, 2016 23:59:59")

find /media/WD/backup/osool/olddata/ -newermt 20120101T1200 -not -newermt 20130101T1400

find . -mtime +1 -mtime -3
find . -mtime +1 -mtime -3 > files_from_yesterday.txt 2>&1
find . -mtime +1 -mtime -3 -ls > files_from_yesterday.txt 2>&1

touch -t 200506011200 first
touch -t 200507121200 last
find / -newer first ! -newer last

#!/bin/bash
for i in `find Your_Mail_Dir/ -newermt "2011-01-01" ! -newermt "2011-12-31"`; do
    mv $i /moved_emails_dir/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code.