# How to read Unix logs being created in a directory in real time?

Tags: unix, redhat, rsync, inotify

I have few scripts (sh) that I call using a main (run_all.sh, contents below) script. So when ever a subscript runs it creates log in logs dir.

```
sh run_one.sh
if [ $? -gt 0 ] ; then
exit 1
fi
sh run_two.sh
if [ $? -gt 0 ] ; then
exit 1
fi
sh run_three.sh
if [ $? -gt 0 ] ; then
exit 1
fi
```

For example it i run the `run_all.sh`, the first script `run_one.sh` starts executing and creates a log file (`log_run_one.log`) in logs dir. So for monitoring the logs I use :

```
tail -f run_one.log
```

Is it possible to make a script (sh) which runs in the logs dir to check if a new file is created and executes `tail -f file_name.log` action on the new log/file created. It should be able to monitor the logs dir for new files/logs and perform `tail` action on all of them one after the other as they are being created. Where should I start? Any help will be appreciated.

I looks like it will be easier in any other programming language by building a  server leveraging some rsync properties to monitor the dir.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cron job to run a find to check if any new files are created in the log folder (Check below article on how to use find with xargs to find and list new files within last few days / time) 
and then just run a tail -f *list of log files provided by above command*

[Linux command to check new files in file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893748/linux-command-to-check-new-files-in-file-system)